# m_pMainWnd changed to NULL in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got this code in the InitInstance function of a class that extends WinApp:

```
m_pMainWnd = &m_Frame;  // Clearly setting m_pMainWnd to !NULL
m_Frame.LoadFrame(BMP_ICON, 0, NULL, NULL);

m_pMainWnd->GetMenu()->Detach();
m_pMainWnd->SetMenu(NULL);

m_Frame.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_Frame.UpdateWindow();
```

Yet when running, the app opens, displays the m_Frame for like a millisecond and then closes again. I get this output:

```
Warning: calling DestroyWindow in CWnd::~CWnd; OnDestroy or PostNcDestroy in derived class will not be called.
Warning: m_pMainWnd is NULL in CWinApp::Run - quitting application.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x914) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6628] VentSizerPro.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

So somewhere along the line m_pMainWnd has been changed to NULL, but where and why and how and what? :(

EDIT:

m_Frame is an instance of a class that exends CFrameWnd to modify the window frame.

Comment: Note that the destructor is being called . You may need to check the scope of m_Frame. Also check what is happening after m_Frame.UpdateWindow.

Comment: What is `m_Frame`: a member of `CWinApp`, an automatic object declared within `InitInstance`, or what? Usually one allocates such an object for `m_pMainWnd` dynamically on heap (this is what MSVC wizard usually does)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be an idiot.. you assigned the pointer value to the value of a local variable.

Comment: I love these soliloquies :) I have them often. Closed this out as too localized.

Comment: @TimPost, aaahh!! When I flaged this post, I didn't noticed he badmouthed himself! :-)))